# SQL Logic to validate Parameter

Tags: sql-server, logic

I have parameter on sql , and I got an issue when it comes to this situation

```
declare @MonRemark varchar(10) = 's'
declare @ConfBy varchar(10)= 's'
declare @confstatus varchar(10)= 's'
declare @StatGD varchar(10)= ''
declare @StatGC varchar(50)= ''
declare @STATGTWO varchar(50)= ''



IF @MonRemark <> '' and  (@ConfBy = '' OR @confstatus = '' and (@StatGD = '' or @StatGC = '' or @STATGTWO = ''))   BEGIN
    print 'a'
END
ELSE IF  @ConfBy  <> '' and (@MonRemark = '' OR @confstatus = '' AND (@StatGD = '' or @StatGC = '' or @STATGTWO = '')) BEGIN
    print 'b'
END
ELSE IF @confstatus  <> '' and @MonRemark = '' AND @ConfBy = '' AND (@StatGD = '' or @StatGC = '' or @STATGTWO = '') BEGIN
    print 'c'
END
ELSE IF   (@StatGD <> '' or @StatGC <> '' or @STATGTWO <> '')  and @confstatus  = '' AND @MonRemark = '' AND @ConfBy = '' BEGIN
    print 'd'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    print 'e'
END
```

if I filled parameter like what I write Above, I wish to get A , but it's always print E, is there any way to get A?

Comment: you will never get A if u fill the ConfBy and the Confstatus with 's'. you will need to change the constant value or the logic rule to get what u want.

Comment: It's like this if you want result  `A`, all the condition must `TRUE` but in there the results are like `IF TRUE and (FALSE and (TRUE)) BEGIN PRINT 'a'`. Your condition return `FALSE` because `@ConfBy` and `@confstatus` are not NULL.  Both `@ConfBy` and `@confstatus` have values `S`

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition. I think @Cyan and @JTR has provided enough explanation on why you get the value 'e'

Try like this, I have modified your condition to get the required results.

```
DECLARE @MonRemark VARCHAR(10) = 's'
DECLARE @ConfBy VARCHAR(10) = 's'
DECLARE @confstatus VARCHAR(10) = 's'
DECLARE @StatGD VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @StatGC VARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @STATGTWO VARCHAR(50) = ''

IF @MonRemark <> ''
    AND (
        (
            @ConfBy = ''
            OR @confstatus = ''
            )
        OR (
            @StatGD = ''
            OR @StatGC = ''
            OR @STATGTWO = ''
            )
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'a'
END
ELSE IF @ConfBy <> ''
    AND (
        @MonRemark = ''
        OR @confstatus = ''
        AND (
            @StatGD = ''
            OR @StatGC = ''
            OR @STATGTWO = ''
            )
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'b'
END
ELSE IF @confstatus <> ''
    AND @MonRemark = ''
    AND @ConfBy = ''
    AND (
        @StatGD = ''
        OR @StatGC = ''
        OR @STATGTWO = ''
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'c'
END
ELSE IF (
        @StatGD <> ''
        OR @StatGC <> ''
        OR @STATGTWO <> ''
        )
    AND @confstatus = ''
    AND @MonRemark = ''
    AND @ConfBy = ''
BEGIN
    PRINT 'd'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'e'
END
```